# Basic R shiny local scoping object

Tags: r, shiny, scoping

I want a local variable in each session that can be updated by an input, which can be used by all other functions in the server. See the simple example below, I want the object to be updated when the user changes value but it doesn't?

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application  

ui =  shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

# Application title
headerPanel("Hello Shiny!"),

# Sidebar with a slider input for data type
sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("data", 
            "Pick letter to us in complex app?", choices = c("A","B"),
             selected = "A")
  ),

# Print letter
 mainPanel(
   textOutput("Print")
 )
))


server =shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  MYLetter = "A";
  updateData = reactive({
    if (input$data == "A") {
      MYLetter <<- "A"
    } else {
      MYLetter <<- "B"
    }
  })
  output$Print <- renderText({ 
    print(MYLetter)
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I feel a solution will be global variables, but if two people are on the app at the same time. Will one person assigning a new value to a global variable change the variable for the other user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple problems with your code. Here is the code that you want, I tried making very minimal changes to your code in order to make it work:

```
ui =  shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

    # Application title
    headerPanel("Hello Shiny!"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for data type
    sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("data", 
                    "Pick letter to us in complex app?", choices = c("A","B"),
                    selected = "A")
    ),

    # Print letter
    mainPanel(
        textOutput("Print")
    )
))


server =shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    MYLetter = reactiveVal("A");
    observe({
        if (input$data == "A") {
            MYLetter("A")
        } else {
            MYLetter("B")
        }
    })
    output$Print <- renderText({ 
        print(MYLetter())
    })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Essentially the two problems were:

1. What you are looking for is creating a reactive value with `reactiveVal()` or `reactiveValues()`. You're absolutely correct that creating a global variable is not the correct solution, because then it would be shared among all the users. It also is not reactive that way.
2. I changed the `reactive({...})` to an `observe({...})`. It's very important to understand the difference between a reactive and an observer. I suggest reading online about it. I changed it to an observe because you weren't returning a value that was being used - rather, you were making an assignment within it.